# phalcon load classes from directory

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, phalcon, autoloader

I have a problem with loading "Model" classes from directory in phalcon framework 2.0.

I can't use namespaces now, because project is migrating step by step from ZF1, and Model classes has many dependencies with themselves. If I register namespaces for every directory - loader works great, but I need to do that without namespaces.

So I do that:

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(
[
    /** Phalcon controllers */
    $configPhalcon->application->controllersDir,
    /** Models */
    $configPhalcon->application->servicesDir,
    ...
    ...
],
true
)->register();
```

Class name are Service_Name(), where Service - directory. File name are Name.php, so I need to register class prefixes for directories:

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(
[
    'Service_' => $configPhalcon->application->servicesDir,
    ...
    ...
],
true
)->register();
```

Now, I want to get my service class:

```
$serv  = new Service_Name();
```

and get Fatal error: Class 'Service_Name' not found. Help me please what I do wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance you misspelled your directory path and a trailing slash is missing?

Comment: trailing slash is on place, load path looks like that:
../zendfr/app/services/

If I register namespace:
     $loader->registerNamespaces(
  [
   'Service' => $configPhalcon->application->servicesDir,
  ],
  true
 )->register();

I can get my class like that:

$serv  = new Service\Name();

but I want to get it by class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for you [Artamiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763926/artamiel) I found the problem! I had phalcon 1.3 and everything works fine, then I updated phalcon to 2.0 version, and didn't test autoload.

The difference is in Prefix for directory classes

in 1.3 version I use 'Service_'

in 2.0 works fine just 'Service'

So, the solution is

```
    $loader->registerPrefixes(
    [
        'Service' => $configPhalcon->application->servicesDir,
        ...
        ...
    ],
    true
    )->register();
```

Comment: Well it wasn't much of a help, but I'm glad you solved your problem.